# Databricks cluster is not getting created using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, databricks, terraform-provider-databricks

I am databricks cluster using terraform with below code.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "myresourcegroup" {
    name     = "${var.applicationName}-${var.environment}-rg"
    location = var.location
    tags = {
        environment = var.environment
    }
}

resource "azurerm_databricks_workspace" "dbworkspace" {
  name                        = "${var.applicationName}-${var.environment}-workspace"
  resource_group_name         = "${var.applicationName}-${var.environment}-rg"
  location                    = var.location
  sku                         = var.databricks_sku

  custom_parameters {
    no_public_ip = "true"
    virtual_network_id = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.id
    public_subnet_name  = azurerm_subnet.public_subnet.name
    private_subnet_name = azurerm_subnet.private_subnet.name
    public_subnet_network_security_group_association_id  = azurerm_subnet.public_subnet.id
    private_subnet_network_security_group_association_id = azurerm_subnet.private_subnet.id
  }

  

  depends_on = [azurerm_resource_group.myresourcegroup, azurerm_network_security_group.nsg, azurerm_virtual_network.vnet, azurerm_subnet.public_subnet, azurerm_subnet.private_subnet, azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association.public-sn-nsg-assoc, azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association.private-sn-nsg-assoc]
}

# Databricks Cluster

resource "databricks_cluster" "dbcluster" {
   cluster_name            = "${var.applicationName}-${var.environment}-cluster"
   spark_version           = "10.4.x-scala2.12"
   node_type_id            = "Standard_DS3_v2"
   autotermination_minutes = 10
   enable_local_disk_encryption = true
   is_pinned               = "true"

   autoscale {
     min_workers = 1
     max_workers = 8
   }

#   spark_conf = {
#     "spark.databricks.delta.optimizeWrite.enabled": true,
#     "spark.databricks.delta.autoCompact.enabled": true,
#     "spark.databricks.delta.preview.enabled": true,    
#   }
    depends_on = [azurerm_resource_group.myresourcegroup, azurerm_network_security_group.nsg, azurerm_virtual_network.vnet, azurerm_subnet.public_subnet, azurerm_subnet.private_subnet, azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association.public-sn-nsg-assoc, azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association.private-sn-nsg-assoc, azurerm_databricks_workspace.dbworkspace]
 }
```

My resource group and databricks workspace are creating fine but databricks cluster is not getting created. When I see plan and apply I can see it is creating. I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: Are there any errors? Have you defined a `databricks` provider block in the `required_providers`?

Comment: What error do you get?